# What is the proper way for working with user changeable settings in an app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, uwp-xaml

Let's say there is a `ThumbnailWidth` variable that user can change and that should be accessible through binding in XAML but also from a class that extracts the thumbnail.

We could add a static class but then the user would not be able to change values defined there. In WPF we could simply use `properties.settings.default.ThumbnailWidth` defined in Settings, but I am not sure if it was the proper way to use it.

What is the way you use in your projects?

Comment: For UWP see app settings documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data

Answer (score 1):

This is how I normally handle my application settings. First, in the window declaration I add the following (it's a custom `XML` namespace declaration that defines the settings location):

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Properties"
```

Then, I bind the setting where needed... for example:

```
<TextBlock Width="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=Width, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=MySetting, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

etc...
```

Finally, I save the modified settings when the application is closed:

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    base.OnClosing(e); 
}
```